# Can't read global constants from constants.php in Laravel when using custom .env file

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, constants

config/constants.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('EXAMPLE_CONSTANT')) define('EXAMPLE_CONSTANT', 'value');
```

In case when I'm using environment file called .env.development which enabled with `php artisan config:cache --env=development` command, I need to define under `autoload` config/constants.php file in composer.json to read EXAMPLE_CONSTANT constant.

Can you Explain why?

Comment: Please take a few step back a try to explain us what the problem is? this is the solution to a problem and with a ton of Laravel applications i been on, never ever did i have to define a constant?

Comment: Hello, when I'm caching ```php artisan config:cache --env=development``` different env file with different variables, some features are not working properly, e.g. global constants not visible which defined in any .php file under config directory and I must to manually add this file path in composer autoload to get constants, is it possible to override builtin laravel function which responsible for that action in AppServiceProvider.php instead?

Comment: Another problem when .env.development file was not visible (after this ```config:cache --env=development```)  for this command ```php artisan key:generate --env=development```, in this case I solved it by adding  ```app()->loadEnvironmentFrom(app()->environmentFile() . '.' . config('app.env'))``` in ```AppServiceProvider.php``` or config:clear -> ...key:generate...->config:cache --env=...